# How do you disable/prevent terminal line wrapping from inside an expect script?

Tags: terminal, expect

I have an expect script which spawns an ssh command to a **router**, and various commands are run to cause data to be returned.

Expect is emulating a terminal, and this emulated terminal has somehow got a fixed width. This causes data returned to be line wrapped, which causes chaos while parsing, for example:

```
+CUSD: 2,"0059[snip]0490\r\n0530[snip]0030", 17
```

The `\r\n` above is the line wrap sent by the router, which believes the terminal has a given width.

What must I tell expect to tell the router either to not line wrap, or that the terminal has many columns? Can the `TERM` environment variable be used for this, and if so, which terminal has no line width?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the screen size with `stty size`, which returns a 2-element list: rows and columns.

```
set cols [lindex [stty size] 1]
```

Now, how to apply that to your spawned session depends on how to spawn it. You might do

```
spawn ssh ...
# expect the prompt, then
send -- "COLUMNS=$cols\r"
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting TERM to "dumb" will often turn off such behaviour.  Whether this works in your case will depend on the router.